# What is a .bitmonero.conf template for setting up a public remote node to be accessed with the monerujo android wallet?

Tags: monerod, rpc, monejuro

I'm trying to setup my own .bitmoner.conf file and looking to create a public node to be used with the android monejuro app. What are the options I need to put in my .bitmonero.conf file? I want to set a custom rpc port, so i know i need: rpc-bind-port

What else do I need so I can protect myself from hacks but also still let me use it as a public node for monejuro?

Does someone have a template one can copy?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is what I have:

```
data-dir=/var/lib/monero
log-file=/var/log/monero/monero.log
log-level=0
no-igd=true

rpc-bind-ip=0.0.0.0
rpc-bind-port=18089
restricted-rpc=true
confirm-external-bind=true
```

You may want to add

```
rpc-login=username:password
```

to restrict access if you must.

You can add comments by starting the line with a `#`.

`log-level=0` reduces the log output of the daemon to a minimum. 4 being the maximum.

Comment: how do you make a comment in the conf file? and what does log-level do? it doesn't say in the --help

Answer (score 0):

i have this with out the logging:

```
no-igd=true

rpc-bind-ip=0.0.0.0
rpc-bind-port=18089
restricted-rpc=true
confirm-external-bind=true

rpc-login=abc:123
```